# Nginx (111: Connection refused) pfp7-fpm.sock (or 9000 port) not found

Tags: php, sockets, nginx, debian, php-7

I have installed PHP 7.0.8 ( ZTS ) on Debian [GitHub Installation](https://github.com/kasparsd/php-7-debian). Debian server work with nginx 1.10.1.

> I have an 111 nginx error :
>
> > [error] 25942#25942: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, request: "GET /phpinfo.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9007"

I found on the web that my error is the pfp7-fpm configuration.
I havn't the file on my server : php7-fpm.sock

Port number 9000 and 9007 don't work and I don't see php-fpm with the following commande : `netstat -lntp`

My php configuration :

```
--prefix=/usr/local/php7 \
--with-config-file-scan-dir=/usr/local/php7/etc/conf.d \
--enable-bcmath \
--enable-calendar \
--enable-exif \
--enable-dba \
--enable-ftp \
--with-gettext \
--with-gd \
--with-jpeg-dir \
--enable-mbstring \
--with-mcrypt \
--with-mhash \
--enable-mysqlnd \
--with-mysql=mysqlnd \
--with-mysql-sock=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock \
--with-mysqli=mysqlnd \
--with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd \
--with-openssl \
--enable-pcntl \
--enable-soap \
--enable-sockets \
--enable-sysvmsg \
--enable-sysvsem \
--enable-sysvshm \
--with-zlib \
--enable-zip \
--with-readline \
--with-curl \
--enable-fpm \
--enable-fastcgi \
--enable-maintainer-zts \
--with-fpm-user=www-data \
--with-fpm-group=www-data"
```

How I can remove this error ?

Comment: If you have installed pthread extension with pecl,  Try to remove pthread extension and restart php-fpm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should star php-fpm first.

The PHP-FPM can be operated using the php7-fpm init script:

And you can see some messages  if you got something wrong .

edit /usr/local/php7/etc/php-fpm.conf

add

```
error_log = /data/log/php/php-fpm.log
```

you can some error messages in this log file

Comment: I havn't any message `service php7-fpm status` : 
> php7-fpm.service - LSB: starts php7-fpm
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/php7-fpm)
   Active: active (exited). My Nginx error : `failed (111: Connection refused)`

Comment: you can add conf like                                                                                 [global]
pid = run/php-fpm.pid
log_level = warning
error_log = /data/log/php/php-fpm.log

Comment: Yes i jave edit /usr/local/php7/etc/php-fpm.conf, I get that in `tail -f /var/log/php7-fpm.log`   [04-Jul-2016 11:18:43] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 24489
[04-Jul-2016 11:18:43] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
[04-Jul-2016 11:28:44] NOTICE: Finishing ...
[04-Jul-2016 11:28:44] NOTICE: exiting, bye-bye!